# Обобщение инициализации ServiceConnection

Tags: java, шаблоны, generics, android-service, android-binder

Каким образом лучше абстрагировать механизм получения методов конкретного `MyService`, и стоят вообще ли свеч попытки уменьшить повторяемость кода в данном случае?

Решение через копирование кода для каждого `Service` (по [android.com/guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html?hl=ru)):

```
/** Точка доступа к ChatServerService. */
private ChatServerService mChatServerService;
/** Точка доступа к ChatClientService. */
private ChatClientService mChatClientService;

/** Объект подключения к Service'у ChatServerService */
private final ServiceConnection mServerConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        // Получение объекта сервиса при успешном подключении
        mChatServerService = ((ChatServerService.LocalBinder) service).getService();
    };

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Неявный разрыв...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mChatServerService = null;
    };
};

/** Объект подключения к Service'у ChatClientService */
private final ServiceConnection mClientConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        // Получение объекта сервиса при успешном подключении
        mChatClientService = ((ChatClientService.LocalBinder) service).getService();
    };

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Неявный разрыв...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mChatClientService = null;
    };
};
```

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42223625/implementing-interface-serviceconnection/

Answer (score 0):

Зачем вы делаете `ServiceConnection` анонимным классом? Сделайте свой класс реализующий интерфейс `ServiceConnection`, типа:

```
public class MyServiceConnection implements ServiceConnection {
    private Class<?> myServiceBinderClz;
    private Service myService;

    public MyServiceConnection(Class<?> myServiceBinderClz) {
        this.myServiceBinderClz=myServiceBinderClz;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        myService = ((myServiceBinderClz) service).getService();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        myService=null;
    }

    public Service getService() {return myService;}
}
```

Тогда вызываем типа:

```
MyServiceConnection myServiceConnection = new MyServiceConnection(ServerChatService.LocalBinder.class);
mServerChatService=myServiceConnection.getService();
```

Просьба ногами не бить, если не компилируется. Тут точно есть синтаксические ошибки - здесь только изложена идея.

Comment: 1) `ServiceConnection` сделан анонимным классом только потому, что это реализация по умолчанию, предлагаемая в гайде android.com;

2) при заходе через `Class<?>` ведь никак не удастся дотянуться до `LocalBinder.getService()`.

Comment: Ну да согласен. Модифицируйте код :) Я просто проиллюстрировал идею